# debug html forms with javascript/dom on a secure web-page

Tags: javascript, html, forms, dom, https

In the old days, it was possible to inject and execute arbitrary javascript on a webpage by going to `javascript:document.forms.FormNameOrId.ElementNameOrId.value="NewInputValue"` in the address bar of the web-browser like Mozilla Application Suite.

However, it seems like this doesn't appear to be working in my newer Mozilla SeaMonkey anymore -- I either get a new page opened up with the content being *NewInputValue*, or, if I append `;return false;` to the above, then nothing appears to happen at all whatsoever.  (I've also tried `javascript:document.forms['FormNameOrId'].elements['ElementNameOrId'].value="NewInputValue"`, but I'm getting the same results.)

What's going on?  How can I debug/modify/append html form data through JavaScript/DOM from a webbrowser like Mozilla SeaMonkey on web-sites that can only be served through the `https://` address scheme?

Comment: Because modern browsers have a JavaScript console. Reason it does not work is security. Look at extensions.

Comment: @epascarello, what security?  It's my browser, it's not like my own browser is supposed to enforce security through obscurity of someone else's site on my behalf.

Comment: Because not everyone understands what they are pasting into the address bar when someone tells them to do it. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=656433

Comment: wow, and i thought the browser was supposed to give me, the advanced user and developer, the power to browse the web the way i please...  well, @epascarello, i won't shoot the messenger, feel free to compose an answer...

Comment: So go into the browser configuration and change it. I think it is browser.urlbar.filter.javascript in regular firefox.

Comment: @epascarello, `browser.urlbar.filter.javascript` setting has an entirely different meaning -- https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=417798, according to http://kb.mozillazine.org/Browser.urlbar.filter.javascript (currently down)